# Unity 3D Help: “Failed to Repackage Resources” and “Failed to convert classes into dex”

Tags: unity-game-engine, chartboost

I have been having issues trying to build an APK file from Unity. I have These files in my Plugin folder That I assume may be causing the problem; play_services_ads.aar, play_services_ads_lite.aar, play_services_base.aar, play_services_basement.aar... whenever I remove one of those I assume are similar e.g, one of the ads and one of the base(play_services_ads.aar and play_services_base.aar for instance), I start getting Unable to repackage resources error. When I put back this files, I start getting errors about unity being Unable to convert classes into Dex format... Someone please SOS! see below;

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Unable to convert classes into dex format. 

See the Console for details.
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_77.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -Xmx2048M -Dcom.android.sdkmanager.toolsdir="/Users/../Library/And/Android/sdk/tools" -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -jar "/Applications/Unity/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/Tools/sdktools.jar" -

stderr[
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zznm;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zznn;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzno;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzno$zza;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zznp;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zznq;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzqi;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzqi$zza;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzqj;
9 errors; aborting
]
stdout[
processing archive /Users/.../Desktop/Game/../Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/ChartboostSDK/libs/./chartboost.jar...
ignored resource META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
processing com/chartboost/sdk/CBImpressionActivity.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/CBImpressionActivity$1.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/CBImpressionActivity$2.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/CBLocation.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/Chartboost.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/Chartboost$1.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/Chartboost$10.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/Chartboost$11.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/Chartboost$12.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/Chartboost$13.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/Chartboost$14.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/Chartboost$15.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/Chartboost$16.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/Chartboost$17.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/Chartboost$18.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/Chartboost$19.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/Chartboost$2.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/Chartboost$20.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/Chartboost$21.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/Chartboost$22.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/Chartboost$23.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/Chartboost$24.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/Chartboost$25.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/Chartboost$26.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/Chartboost$27.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/Chartboost$28.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/Chartboost$29.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/Chartboost$3.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/Chartboost$30.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/Chartboost$31.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/Chartboost$32.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/Chartboost$33.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/Chartboost$34.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/Chartboost$35.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/Chartboost$4.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/Chartboost$5.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/Chartboost$6.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/Chartboost$7.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/Chartboost$8.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/Chartboost$9.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/Chartboost$CBFramework.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/Chartboost$CBMediation.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/Chartboost$a.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/ChartboostActivity.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/ChartboostDelegate.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/InPlay/CBInPlay.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/InPlay/a.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/InPlay/a$1.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/InPlay/a$2.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/InPlay/a$a.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/InPlay/a$b.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/Libraries/CBLogging.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/Libraries/CBLogging$Level.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/Libraries/CBUtility.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/Libraries/a.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/Libraries/a$1.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/Libraries/b.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/Libraries/c.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/Libraries/c$1.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/Libraries/c$a.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/Libraries/d.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/Libraries/e.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/Libraries/e$1.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/Libraries/e$a.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/Libraries/e$b.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/Libraries/f.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/Libraries/g.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/Libraries/g$1.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/Libraries/g$a.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/Libraries/g$b.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/Libraries/g$c.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/Libraries/g$d.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/Libraries/g$e.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/Libraries/g$f.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/Libraries/g$g.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/Libraries/g$h.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/Libraries/g$i.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/Libraries/g$j.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/Libraries/g$k.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/Libraries/g$l.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/Libraries/g$m.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/Libraries/g$n.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/Libraries/g$o.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/Libraries/g$p.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/Libraries/g$q.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/Libraries/h.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/Libraries/h$a.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/Libraries/i.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/Libraries/j.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/Libraries/j$1.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/Libraries/j$2.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/Libraries/j$a.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/Libraries/k.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/Model/CBError.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/Model/CBError$1.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/Model/CBError$CBClickError.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/Model/CBError$CBImpressionError.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/Model/CBError$a.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/Model/a.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/Model/a$1.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/Model/a$a.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/Model/a$b.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/Model/a$c.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/Model/a$d.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/Model/a$e.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/Model/b.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/Tracking/CBAnalytics.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/Tracking/CBAnalytics$1.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/Tracking/CBAnalytics$CBIAPPurchaseInfo.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/Tracking/CBAnalytics$CBIAPType.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/Tracking/CBAnalytics$CBLevelType.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/Tracking/a.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/a.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/b.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/b$1.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/b$2.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/b$3.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/b$4.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/b$5.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/b$a.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/b$b.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/b$c.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/b$d.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/b$e.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/c.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/c$1.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/c$a.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/d.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/d$1.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/d$1$1.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/d$2.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/d$3.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/d$4.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/d$a.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/d$b.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/e.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/e$1.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/e$2.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/e$3.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/e$4.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/e$4$1.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/e$4$2.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/e$a.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/f.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/f$1.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/f$2.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/f$2$1.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/f$2$1$1.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/f$3.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/g.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/g$1.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/g$a.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/g$a$1.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/g$b.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/h.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/h$1.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/h$2.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/h$3.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/h$a.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/h$b.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/h$c.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/a.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/aa.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/ab.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/ac.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/ad.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/ad$1.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/ae.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/ae$1.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/ae$1$1.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/ae$2.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/ae$2$1.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/ae$3.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/af.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/af$1.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/ag.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/ag$a.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/ag$a$1.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/ag$a$2.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/ah.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/ah$1.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/ah$2.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/ah$a.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/ah$a$1.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/ah$a$2.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/ah$a$3.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/ah$a$4.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/ah$a$5.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/ah$b.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/ai.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/aj.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/ak.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/ak$1.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/al.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/al$1.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/al$2.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/al$a.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/am.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/an.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/an$1.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/an$2.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/an$3.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/an$4.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/an$5.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/ao.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/ap.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/aq.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/aq$1.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/ar.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/ar$1.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/ar$2.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/as.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/as$1.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/at.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/au.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/au$1.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/av.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/av$1.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/av$a.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/av$a$1.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/av$a$a.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/av$a$a$1.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/av$b.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/aw.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/aw$1.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/ax.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/ax$a.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/ax$b.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/ay.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/ay$a.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/ay$b.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/ay$c.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/ay$d.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/ay$e.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/az.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/az$1.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/az$a.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/az$b.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/az$c.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/az$d.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/az$e.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/az$e$a.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/b.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/b$a.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/ba.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/ba$1.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/ba$1$1.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/ba$a.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/bb.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/bb$a.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/bb$a$1.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/bb$a$2.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/bb$a$3.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/bb$b.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/bb$c.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/bc.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/bc$1.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/bc$a.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/bd.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/bd$1.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/bd$2.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/bd$3.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/bd$4.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/bd$5.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/bd$6.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/be.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/be$1.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/be$2.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/be$3.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/be$4.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/be$5.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/bf.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/bf$a.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/bg.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/bg$1.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/bg$2.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/bg$3.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/bg$a.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/bg$b.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/bh.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/bi.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/bj.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/bj$1.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/bj$2.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/bj$a.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/bk.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/bk$1.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/bk$1$1.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/bk$2.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/bk$a.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/bk$b.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/bl.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/bm.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/bn.class...
processing com/chartboost/sdk/impl/bo.class...
proc<message truncated>
```

Answer (score 2):

i have also same error in my game simple way to resolve this replace **GoogleMobileAds** , **PlayServicesResolver** and **Plugins** with latest version...

In my project it runs properly hope it will work.

Answer (score 0):

In the inspector, click on the tab "Services", and disable the "ADS" option, and try again.